# Is there a way to get posts from our facebook fanpage users via FB API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

Is there a way to get posts from our fanpage users (the things that our fans post on our fanpage wall) via FB API (app)?

I have been looking for a while but could not find any helpful resource regarding to that.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the posts by others on your Page's wall you can use [Stream FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream) like,

```
select message,actor_id from stream
where source_id=Your+Page_ID and actor_id != source_id
```

Which would retrieve the Posts on your Page wall authored by people other than you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `PAGE_ID/feed/` connection. Posts and comments should be in there you just have to filter it.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

Example try the Python page - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=pythonlang%2Ffeed